# Remove trailing slash in .htaccess for CloudFront use

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cdn

There are plenty of 'remove trailing slash' bits of regex here on StackOverflow, and they're all lovely, but they all have the same issue: they don't work too well with a CDN service like Amazon CloudFront.

So, my setup is that www.example.com is Amazon Cloudfront, while my real website is, say, on real.example.com.

All the three below will happily remove trailing slashes from **www.example.com/directory/** but will rewrite the URL as **real.example.com/directory** which clearly I don't want.

I've used

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ %{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

...but all of these will expose the 'real' domain name.

How can I write a regex rewrite rule that will correctly remove the trailing slash but not rewrite the domain to the origin website?

(I don't mind hard-coding the domain URL in here, but I need to keep the http or https bit intact.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this?

```
# Set "protossl" to "s" if we were accessed via https://. This is used later
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^ - [E=protossl:s]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Oh, I forgot about the http/https problem. Sorry!

This could maybe handled with another rewriterule above. Give me 5 minutes...

Comment: In fact, is the RewriteCond to check that it is not a directory really useful?

Comment: The server doesn't really know whether it's https or not, since CloudFront handles all that, and all the server sees is an http call internal from CloudFront I suspect I'll fix it to always point to the https, for security's sake, which might then forward back to the http for those who don't have access. Sigh